# How to access the context menu for attachments in outlook 2003?

Tags: c#, outlook

My requirement is to capture the click events in attachment item's context menu in Outlook 2003. I tried binding existing outlook item events but none of them fires at all. Is there a way to accomplish my requirement ? Is there a way to get hold of the context menu for attachments ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook 2003 uses command bars. You need to use the [OnUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861536.aspx) event of the CommandBars class to find the context menu (if any).

Comment: Yes. This can get me the context menu. I bound click events for each item in the receiving context menu. but . ... The attachment context menu items wont get bound :(

Comment: I am getting the context menu at firing of `CommandBars.OnUpdate` event.
if such a command bar named "Context menu" exist, store it in a `CommandBar` variable. Then store the `CommandBarButton` controls in a `List` control.  Then binding the click events per each item in `List` Control.

my sample code to achieve this is available in following link (sorry for the hassle :( )
[https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DFwqynQIhNd8_8fpVhtnmxkeT4mzX7FBdEitTekBIGI/edit?usp=sharing]